# UITableView reload data does work on IOS 7, but works in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

I have a `UITableView` `IBOutlet` in my controller class. It is hidden by default, but on text field editing, it calls google places to load the cities, matching with the text entered in the text field.

When the text changes, I get the results from google places api, unhide the table and then call table reload data method.

```
self.cityAutocompleteList.hidden = false            
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
{
   self.cityAutocompleteList.reloadData()
})
```

The `numberOfRowsInSection` shows the rows correctly. But the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being fired.

Everything works correctly on iOS Simulator iPhone5s, but its not working on my iPhone running iOS 7.1.

EDIT:

I also tried updating in the main queue like below, but still doesn't work.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
{
    self.cityAutocompleteList.reloadData()
})
```

**Update 1:**
In fact even if the table is not hidden to begin with, it is not being displayed.

**Update 2:**
After some searching, I found out that it is not recommended to add a tableview to a scrollview, and as a result the tableView is not showing up even when it is not hidden. But my problem is this, I need a drop-down like behaviour, on the textfield. All the text fields are inside a scrollview, because I move the text field up when being edited, so as not to be hidden by the keyboard. So how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Please, provide all code, so I can run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to happen on the main thread you need to do this:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //Your code goes in here
  NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");       
});
```

Use the following in swift:

```
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            println("Main Thread Code")
            })
```

Your code seems to be pushing the reload to a background thread that will ensure that table view doesnt get updated

In this case the tableview was inside the scrollview which is not right.

Comment: Can you please provide a swift version of this code?

Comment: I added it.. hope that helps

Comment: I tried this, but now my screen is freezing, infact the app completely freezes.

Comment: hmm looks like the sync might be a prob. Try dispatch_async.. dispatch_sync uses a semaphore to execute and its possible that it is not getting it. I am not sure if this will work exactly. We would have to look at what all thread activity is going on here.

Comment: ok that does not freeze the app anymore, but still my table is not showing up with the results.

Comment: can you add the code where you have the user enter the text, and the results from the google api are coming back. If its easier we can move this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57523/discussion-between-srinivas-and-hackerinheels).